# Getting PhpStorm's live templates to work outside of PHP tags

Tags: phpstorm, live-templates

I've added a live template that should tab-trigger on `php` to `<?php $END$ ?>`. I've added one in the PHP live templates group, in the HTML live templates group and in the user (custom thingers) live templates group, where in "Applicable in .." I've checked *everything*.

But they don't work outside of `<?php..?>` tags in php documents... where is the magic "make it work" checkbox?

Update 1:

It *is* listed if I invoke `Code | Insert Live Template` (inside and outside php tags), and works as it should there.

Screenshot as requested:
[image]

Comment: 1) Screenshot of your Live Template please. 2)  Will it be listed if you invoke `Code | Insert Live Template`? 3) There is no need to have multiple entries in different groups -- groups are for organising only; the key is the right context (that "Applicable in" thingy)

Comment: Updated as requested

Comment: So .. what happens when you type `php` in a HTML file and press `Tab` to expand it? Anything at all? Seems to work OK here in Blade and plain HTML file: https://postimg.org/image/4njw2u014b/ P.S. Please delete the same template from other groups -- you should only have one.

Comment: I've removed them from the other groups, it's now only in the "user" group.
In a HTML file: It adds spaces to a multiple of 4 for the characters on that line - is it called soft tabs? Ctrl-J brings up the available LTs and works fine.
I've checked whether I've re-assigned the tab key to other things, but can't find anything, and in between `<?php .. ?>` all the templates work fine. More or less given up for it today, behind with work, but suggestions always welcome.

Comment: Try disabling custom plugins to see if any of them are interfering. Check idea.log (Help | Show Log in...) for possible hints. As for `Tab` shortcuts -- `Settings/Preferences | Keyamp` -- it has a button next to search field that allows to search for actions by assigned shortcuts. *"is it called soft tabs"* sorry, I do not know what you mean here and what is happening there. Some screenshots (better screencast) are more than welcome. I personally do not know what else it may be.

Answer (score 2):

So.. I found "a solution".

If I'm typing in HTML (in a .php file) and type `<php`, THEN it will offer the live template and expand to `<<?php  ?>`. I have tried a fair few other punctuation marks instead of `<` but that one seems special. Fortunately my template text starts with the `<` too so I just removed that leading character from it, leaving this:
[image: Live template preferences]

I have *no* idea what is going *on* inside PHPStorm but I'll take it..
It is the same for the other snippets in that list, so it's not treating the 'php' string special.

Comment: Also also, they don't work in PHP comments, despite that being checked in the "Applicable in" list. They do work in SQL comment. Not in JavaScript comments. (fwiw, I checked all the boxes). PHPStorm looks like it could be a really great application, if they fixed all these tiny wtf'y issues)